# Lagrangian to Eulerian coordinates

Tags: fluid-dynamics, coordinate-systems, flow

I have a 1D fluid and at a time t0 I know the speed of all its particles. So I can know the future position of every particle. Given a particle at position x0 at time t0, i can know its position at any future time. If I am not wrong this is called the [lagrangian coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_and_Eulerian_specification_of_the_flow_field).

My problem is that with this information I want to know the speed of the fluid at any time in any position. I don´t want to be following the particles but I want to be able see what happens at a fixed position. I think this is called the eulerian coordinates.

How do I make this change of variables?

Comment: You need to use the definition of the [material, or substantial, derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_derivative).

Comment: How i should use it? im confused because to use it i need to know the flow velocity but that is precisely the thing i want to calculate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the Eulerian velocity you must first know the full Lagrangian description. The Lagrangian description means you know the trajectory $\vec X$ of the particles,
$$\vec X(\vec x_0, t),$$
from which you can derive the particles velocity:
$$\vec V(\vec x_0, t)=\frac{d}{dt}\vec X(\vec x_0, t).$$
To get the Eulerian velocity at a certain position $\vec x$, you set it equal to $\vec X$ and solve for $x_0$. You will get $x_0$ as a function of $x$ and $t$.
$$\vec x=\vec X(\vec x_0, t)\rightarrow\vec x_0=\vec x_0(x, t)$$
What you are doing here is basically asking the question 'what was the starting point of the particle that is currently at $x$? '. This is useful because now you can plug $x_0$ in $\vec V$. Now you are done because you know the velocity of the particle currently at $x$, so you can just set 
$$\vec u(\vec x,t)=\vec V(\vec x_0,t)$$

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: Yes.  Let $x(x_0, t_0, t)$ represent the x location at time t of the material particle that was at $x_0$ at time $t_0$.  So the velocity u(x,t) is given by $$u(x,t)=\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}\right)_{x_0,t_0}$$

Comment: Im sorry to reask. What happens if the funtion x⃗ =X⃗ (x⃗ 0,t) is not invertible? is there any other method?

Comment: @Math.w What function is $X$ exactly? I'm not sure if there are other methods