# Lagrangian to Eulerian coordinates when the relation between coordinates is not invertible

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I am solving a problem that involves going from Lagrangian to Eulerian coordinates. I have asked for a method to solve this and the suggestion was:

[Lagrangian to Eulerian coordinates](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/399239/lagrangian-to-eulerian-coordinates)

My problem is that i can not apply that solution because my equation is not invertible. I get for example X = x0 + sin x0. So I can not obtain x0(X).

Is there any alternative method of changing coordinates?

In my previous question I have also been suggested to use the material derivative, How do I use it?

Comment: What is the exact problem statement?

Comment: There is no time dependence in your equation.

Comment: I have the position of every paricle of a fluid at time t0 and posterior times. Mathematically this means that I have a X(x0,t). With this i can obtain their speed V(x0,t). What i need to calculate is the speed of the fluid at a fixed position u(X,t). It was suggested in the other post to invert the relation of X(x0,t) to x0(X,t) and with that calculate u(X,t). My problem is that i get relations  X(x0,t) that are not invertible. For example X = x0 + t * sin x0. What should I do in this case?